Photos transfer from mac-book air to a hard disk
I have 7800 Photos on my photos of mac-book air, i need to transfer all the 7800 photos to a external harddisk. I created a separate folder with all the 7800 photos on the desktop now when i try to drag and drop the folder on the harddisk location it pulls back the folder to its original place. The hard disk has enough storage to accomodate the photos i am trying to transfer and the Format of the harddisk is Windows NT File System(NTFS). Please suggest

Did you install specific software/drivers for this, which would have added NTFS write functionality to macOS?

What @nohillside is saying is that you can't write to an NTFS formatted drive on a Mac without third party software that enables you to do so. Paragon makes such software (I think) or you could reformat the drive in a Mac format (HFS+ or APFS) or a PC format like ExFAT which the Mac can write to.

You would get more cogent answers if you described your purpose.  For example, it might be for backup, for transfer to Windows, or to relieve space constraints on the MBA - each of those would glean different advice.
